# Work and gravitational potential energy in taking a book in different definition of "system"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work

Can some body calculate the work done by person A in moving the book to height $h$ from ground in following three definitions of the system, where initaiial and final velocities are zero:

a) only book is considered as system

b) book and earth considered as system

c) earth, book and person A considered as a system.

Also i am confused about as to why work in all above cases may be different? what
is implication from physics point of view.

Comment: 1) Are all three in the same reference frame? 2) What are the initial and final velocities?  3) What do you think the answers are and why do you think that?  4) If you think they are all the same, what is your reasoning?

Comment: Are you sure it’s asking for work done by the person and not the net work done on the “system”?